# expected class name before '{' token. C++ inheritance issue

Tags: c++, inheritance, compilation

I've been on this for ages and did a lot of research and couldn't find an answer.
I have 4 classes: BuildingBase, CustomBuildingBase, Attackable, Nexus.
CustomBuildingBase is inherited from BuildingBase and Attackable, Nexus is inherited from CustomBuildingBase

I get this error in my nexus.h file

```
expected class name before '{' token.
```

My code:

custombuildingbase.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMBUILDINGBASE_H
#define CUSTOMBUILDINGBASE_H

#include "buildings/buildingbase.h"

#include "handlerandmanager/gameeventhandler.h"
#include "handlerandmanager/gamemanager.h"

#include "attackable.h"

namespace Whiskas {


class CustomBuildingBase : public Course::BuildingBase, public Attackable
{
public:

   CustomBuildingBase() = delete;

    explicit CustomBuildingBase(
            const std::shared_ptr<gameEventHandler>& eventhandler,
            const std::shared_ptr<gameManager>& objectmanager,
            const std::shared_ptr<Course::PlayerBase>& owner,
            const int& tilespaces = 1,
            const Course::ResourceMap& buildcost = {},
            const Course::ResourceMap& production = {},
            int health=3,
            int attack=0
            );
};

}

#endif // BUILDINGBASE_H
```

nexus.h:

```
#ifndef NEXUS_H
#define NEXUS_H

#include "buildings/custombuildingbase.h"
#include "core/resourcemaps.h"

namespace Whiskas {

static const Course::ResourceMap OUTPOST_PRODUCTIONMAP = {
  {Course::BasicResource::MONEY, -10}
};

class Nexus : public CustomBuildingBase
{                     //<--------------this is where I get the error
public:
    Nexus() = delete;

    explicit Nexus(
            const std::shared_ptr<gameEventHandler>& eventhandler,
            const std::shared_ptr<gameManager>& objectmanager,
            const std::shared_ptr<Course::PlayerBase>& owner,
            const int& tilespaces = 1,
            const Course::ResourceMap& buildcost = Course::ConstResourceMaps::OUTPOST_BUILD_COST,
            const Course::ResourceMap& production = Course::ConstResourceMaps::OUTPOST_PRODUCTION,
            int health = 3,
            int attack = 0
            );

    virtual ~Nexus() = default;
    virtual std::string getType() const override;
    virtual void onBuildAction() override;
    virtual Course::ResourceMap getProduction() override;

}; // class Nexus

} // namespace Whiskas


#endif // NEXUS_H
```

Comment: Does one of the files that is included in `custombuildingbase.h` include `nexus.h`?

Comment: Check for `#include` loops

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: Why did you opt for a design with multiple inheritance?

Comment: @NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica that was the problem, thank you. I can't believe my friend and I spent hours on this problem.

Comment: Do *not* mark a question as "solved" in the title or body. A question is marked as solved when an answer is accepted. If there are no answers that solve the question, write your own solution and accept it.

Comment: @crashmstr how do I accept an answer if it's a comment?

Comment: You cannot accept a comment as an answer, but you or the person who commented could write an answer.